# Error printing an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, printf

The error occurs in the line:

```
printf("\n%s was found at word number(s): %d\n", search_for, pos);
```

I want to print my array of ints (`pos`) but I am not sure how to do so. I am running it through the command line and I am getting this error:

```
search_word.c:57:28: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument hastype 'int *' [-Wformat] search_for, pos);
```

Code:

```
const int MAX_STRING_LEN = 100;

void Usage(char prog_name[]);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char search_for[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    char current_word[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int  scanf_rv;
    int loc = 0;
    int pos[MAX_STRING_LEN] = {0};
    int word_count = 0;
    int freq = 0;

    /* Check that the user-specified word is on the command line */
    if (argc != 2) Usage(argv[0]);
    strcpy(search_for, argv[1]);

    printf("Enter the text to be searched\n");
    scanf_rv = scanf("%s", current_word);
    while ( scanf_rv != EOF && strcmp(current_word, search_for) != MAX_STRING_LEN )  {
        if (strcmp(current_word, search_for) == 0) {
            loc++;
            freq++;
            pos[loc] = word_count;
        }
        word_count++;
        scanf_rv = scanf("%s", current_word);
    }
    if (freq == 0)
        printf("\n%s was not found in the %d words of input\n",
               search_for, word_count);
    else
        printf("\n%s was found at word number(s): %d\n",
               search_for, pos);
    printf("The frequency of the word was: %d\n", freq);

    return 0;
}  /* main */

/* If user-specified word isn't on the command line,
 * print a message and quit
 */
void Usage(char prog_name[]) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s <string to search for>\n",
            prog_name);
    exit(0);
}  /* Usage */
```

Comment: Just as the compiler tells you, `pos` is a pointer to `int`, not an `int`.  It's a whole array full of their kind.  Which one do you want to print?

Comment: I want to print the whole array of ints that I have stored

Comment: Then you need to use a loop.

Comment: Then you'll need to loop over it and print one at a time.  I recommend you write a helper function for this.

Comment: If 3 matches are found, do you want to print just those 3 positions, or those 3, plus the rest of the array (filled with 0s)?

Answer (score 1):

`pos` is an array. You have to print it in a loop.

Do

```
else {
    printf("\n%s was found at word number(s): ",
           search_for);
    for (int index = 0; index < MAX_STRING_LEN; index++)
          printf("%d ", pos[index]);

    printf("\n");
 }
```

Comment: What if not all `MAX_STRING_LEN` slots in `pos` were used?

Comment: In the problem OP stated that it wants to print the whole array.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to loop over the array. C doesn't have any way to print an array of `int`s in a single statement:

```
else {
  int i;

  printf("\n%s was found at word number(s): ", search_for);

  for ( i = 0; i < loc; ++i ) {
    if (i > 0)
      printf(", ");
    printf("%d", pos[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Before that, though, make sure you increment `loc` at the right time. As-is, you're leaving the first element empty.

```
if (strcmp(current_word, search_for) == 0) {
  pos[loc] = word_count;
  loc++;
  freq++;
}
```

Comment: great. this worked. I was just unaware that one has to iterate through an array to print. Now i know.